# Using an HTML entity in XSLT (e.g. &nbsp;)

Tags: xslt

What is the best way to include an html entity in XSLT?

```
<xsl:template match="/a/node">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&nbsp;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

this one returns a **XsltParseError**

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can use CDATA section

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
```

or you can describe &nbsp in local DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
```

or just use `&#160;` instead of `&nbsp;`

Comment: "or just use `&#160;` instead of `&nbsp;`" ❤️

Answer (score 26):

It is also possible to extend the approach from 2nd part of [aku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp#31873) and get all known character references available, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY % w3centities-f PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES Combined Set//EN//XML"
      "http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/w3centities-f.ent">
  %w3centities-f;
]>
...
<xsl:text>&nbsp;&minus;30&deg;</xsl:text>
```

There is certain difference in the result as compared to `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">` approach. The latter one is going to produce string literals like `&nbsp;` for all kinds of output, even for `<xsl:output method="text">`, and this may happen to be different from what you might wish... On the contrary, getting entities defined for XSLT template via `<!DOCTYPE ... <!ENTITY ...` will always produce output consistent with your `xsl:output` settings.

It may be wise then to use a local entity resolver to keep the XSLT engine from fetching character entity definitions from the Internet. JAXP or explicit Xalan-J users may need a patch for Xalan-J to use the resolver correctly. See my blog [XSLT, entities, Java, Xalan...](http://s-n-ushakov.blogspot.com/2011/09/xslt-entities-java-xalan.html) for patch download and comments.

Comment: This is beautiful- wish it was more well known

Answer (score 15):

one other possibility to use html entities from within xslt is the following one:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: The unicode character &#160 was giving question marks and boxes, outputting the un-escaped html entity worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

XSLT only handles the five basic entities by default: `lt`, `gt`, `apos`, `quot`, and `amp`. All others need to be defined as [@Aku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-eg-nbsp#31873) mentions.

Answer (score 6):

> this one returns a **XsltParseError**

Yes, and the reason for that is that `&nbsp;` is not a predefined entity in XML or XSLT as it is in HTML.

You could just use the unicode character which `&nbsp;` stands for: `&#160;`

Answer (score 5):

Now that there's Unicode, it's generally counter-productive to use named character entities.  I would recommend using the Unicode character for a non-breaking space instead of an entity, just for that reason.  Alternatively, you could use the entity `&#160`;, instead of the named entity.  Using named entities makes your XML dependent on an inline or external DTD.

Answer (score 1):

I found all of these solutions produced a Â character in the blank space.

Using `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` solved the problem for me; but `<xsl:text>#x20;</xsl:text>` might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your information. I have written a short blog post based on what worked for me as I was doing XSLT transformation in a template of the [Dynamicweb CMS](http://www.dynamicweb.com).

The blog post is here: [How to add entities to XSLT templates](http://www.netsi.dk/wordpress/index.php/2012/01/18/how-to-add-entities-to-xslt-templates/).

/Sten Hougaard

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use the entity  **#x160;**

Comment: It's _not_ x160 but decimal 160.

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with the DOCTYPE approach from Aku.

What worked for me in MSXML transforms on an Windows 2003 server, was

```
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#160;</xsl:text>
```

Sort of a hybrid of the above.  Thanks Stackoverflow contributors!

Answer (score -3):

One space character between text tags should be enough.