# XML in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt

All,

I am inserting as xml datatype in a table, an XSLT document.
Somewhere in my XSLT document I am using the character

```
&#60;
```

for a reason.
However when inserting to the table, the SQL Server replaces the

```
&#60;
```

with

```
&lt;
```

Any ideas how to store it without having SQL Server to change it?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 2):

`&#60;` is the character `<` and this is the same as `&lt;`. XML is not a string. Two different representations can encode the same underlying XML and correctly written applications *cannot* distinguish between them. If your application relies on `&#60;` to exists in the XML, it cannot be correct.

Comment: The reason I need it is because I am replacing a string with XML tags in XSLT. 
    <xsl:with-param name="substringOut" select="''&#60;/coord&#62;&#60;coord&#62;''" />

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp