# xslt not supporting registered trade mark symbol

Tags: java, character-encoding, xslt

How to display registered trademark symbol `®` using xslt. When transforming to xslt it is not display the correct symbol.

```
 String reg = dirspechars("stackoverflow ®",getspechar()) 

 getspechars()
 {
  spechars.put("®","&#174;")
  }
```

---

```
 <xsl:value-of select="@reg"/>
```

and this string passing to xsl and converting to html.I tried with encoding character also `\u00AE`, even i am getting problem Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

As i coded the xsl version1.0 and encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" eventhough it is not displaying correct trade mark symbol.

Please

Comment: Seems like you completely forgot to provide your XSLT transformation, the source XML document, the expected result and the actual result from the transformation. As of now, this question is not at all an XSLT question.

Comment: This is an encoding issue of your transformation's result **consumer**. Check my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Try specifying the entity by number:  `&#174;`

Comment: See also this answer which includes 2 additional options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp/31873#31873

Answer (score 0):

> i coded the xsl version1.0 and
>   encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"
>   eventhough it is not displaying
>   correct trade mark symbol.

This is an *encoding* problem of the transformation's result **consumer**.

If that is a browser (say IE) would'n known anything about UTF-8 encoding and display `Â®`. **You must declare the encoding.** In HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Output ® test</title>
    </head>
    <body>®</body>
</html>
```

That will be correctly produce by this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Output ® test</title>
            </head>
            <body>&#174;</body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```