# Servlet not retrieve parameters from AJAX call

Tags: java, ajax, xslt, servlets

I used AJAX to call an action and pass parameters, the AJAX call occurs from xsl page and its as follows:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET","examcont?action=AJAX_SectionsBySessionId&amp;sessionId="+sessionId,true);
```

I decided to put the `amp;` after `&` as xsl raises this error when I removed it:

```
The reference to entity "sessionId" must end with the ';' delimiter
```

the problem is that the action is unable to read the parameter `sessionId` however I tried the same action URL but without the `amp;` and the action reads the parameter successfully

Comment: Then what is your problem?

Comment: "the problem is that the action is unable to read the parameter sessionId"

Comment: The `&amp;` is just a quoted `&` in XML/XSL, i.e. the output from the XSL should actually be `&`. Can you check the output of the XSL?

Comment: alert("examcont?action=AJAX_SectionsBySessionId&amp;sessionId="+sessionId);outputs the &amp;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `&amp;` represents `&` in the style sheet but gets expanded/escaped to `&amp;` again during output (because it is HTML/XML). You may try to use the following in XSL to avoid escaping:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET","examcont?action=AJAX_SectionsBySessionId<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>sessionId="+sessionId,true);
```

However, note that - if you happen to let your XSL run in the browser - this does *not* work (although it is correct XSL and it should) on Firefox according to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98168.

As portable alternative, you can use the following which avoids mentioning `&` by inserting it at runtime with what you might call "Javascript-escaping":

```
xmlHttp.open("GET","examcont?action=AJAX_SectionsBySessionId"+String.fromCharCode(38)+"sessionId="+sessionId,true);
```

Also have a look at similar question with deeper discussion and other options [using a html entity in xslt (e.g. &nbsp;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp)