# Using html entities in value-of in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, html-entities

Here is my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="a/b" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<a><b>four &lt; five</b></a>
```

I would like the output

> four < five

but I get

> four

Clearly there is a problem with XSLT understanding the `&lt;` entity. I have read this question

- [using a html entity in xslt (e.g. &nbsp;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp/31873#31873)

but do not find it quite relevant because it pertains to the `xsl:text` tag, whereas I am interested in the `xsl:value-of` tag.

By the way, I am unable to modify the XML file.

Comment: You're showing you transformation result in a browser? If so, check your page source, the `<` character should be there but browser understood it as a broken markup.

Comment: Thanks Rubens, I'd forgotten that! In which case, I guess I should have said that I want XSLT to produce `four &lt; five`, so that my browser can then produce `four < five`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Your stylesheet generates a result of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>four &lt; five`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Oh, that's odd. I used http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog . If you copy my XML snippet into the left-hand box, and my XSLT snippet into the right-hand box, does it work for you?

Comment: This is most likely w3schools being rubbish. (If you enter `<a><b>four &amp;lt; five</b></a>` you will should get your expected output, although this is not the correct thing to do!). Try it at http://xmlplayground.com/ or http://xsltransform.net/ and you will see there is actually no problem with your code at all.

Comment: @TimC Many thanks, I shall use those websites instead of w3schools in future. My issue has now been resolved, so do feel free to turn your comment into an answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely w3schools being not up to a good standard. If you enter `<a><b>four &amp;lt; five</b></a>` you will should get your expected output, although this is not the correct thing to do!

Using `&lt;` as the entity is the correct thing to do in the XML. And when the resultant XML gets serialised, it should also be output as `&lt;`

Try it at [xmlplayground.com](http://xmlplayground.com/) or [xsltransform.net](http://xsltransform.net/) and you will see there is actually no problem with your code at all.

As an aside, if you are intending to show the results in the browser, you should probably add the **xsl:output** statement to indicate you are outputting HTML. (And to stop the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` declaration being output).

```
<xsl:output method="html" />
```