# Table not rendering correctly in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a table being rendered through XSLT . The issue is if there is no data for the @station variable i need a empty cell with the borders as is present in the CSS for the td but if there is no data it does not render the border. It does renders the borders if there is data in the td . Can someone please tell me what do I need to do if I need to have borders regardless of the data in td.

```
<xsl:template match="version">
  <tr>

     <td nowrap="true" style="border-top:1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black">
       <content><xsl:value-of select="@station"/></content>
     </td>

  </tr>    
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `&nbsp;` in case station is either empty or not there:

```
<xsl:template match="version">
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="true" style="border-top:1px solid black;
        border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black">
      <content>
         <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" 
          select="if( @station and not(@station ='')) then @station 
                  else '&amp;nbsp;'"/>     
      </content>
    </td>
  </tr>    
</xsl:template>
```

As there may be better solutions, depending on your settings, you can check various suggestions here: [using a html entity in xslt (e.g. &nbsp;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp)
A different approach would be to solve this issue using CSS: if you would add

```
 empty-cells: show;
```

to the style of the `td` the borders should display.
If you would like to display the borders for all empty cells, it could even be easier just to set the style to the surrounding table. You can check various suggestions given here: [CSS to make an empty cell's border appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear) but have to consider browser compability.

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/empty-cells