# How to process HTML entities in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xhtml, saxon

I am trying to transform XHTML that contains the `&nbsp;` entity. Saxon complains that the entity is not defined. How can I define it?

Is it possible to add the entity definition at the beginning of the stylesheet? As suggested
here:
http://s-n-ushakov.blogspot.com/2011/09/xslt-entities-java-xalan.html
or here:
[Using an HTML entity in XSLT (e.g. &nbsp;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-an-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp)

My puny attempt, ignored by Saxon, was to add the following to the beginning of the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY nbsp  "&#x000A0;">
]>
```

I am using Saxon 9.9 PE.
The HTML I am trying to transform is a complete document, not just a fragment.

Comment: You would have to include the `<!ENTITY>` definitions in the XHTML source, not in your stylesheet, I assume.

Comment: Which version and edition of Saxon? Is the XHTML input a complete document or a fragment?

Comment: See edits above. The input is a complete HTML document and I am using Saxon 9.9 PE.
I was hoping that there were other ways than including the <!ENTITY> definition to the source, but if that is the more straightforward approach, I will try that.

Comment: A complete, well-formed XHTML document using entity references like `&nbsp;` should declare an XHTML DOCTYPE that references an XHTML DTD declaring the entities.

Comment: Note that with PE you have access to Saxon extension functions like `saxon:parse-html` (not sure whether I remember the right name), this should work to parse HTML, although as `text/html`, not as `application/xhtml+xml`. But entities for HTML are surely supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to pass the URL of the XHTML to the XSLT as a parameter, which would read the XHTML *as text* using the `unparsed-text()` function, expand the entity reference using the `replace()` function, and parse the result using the `parse-xml()` function. e.g.

```xml
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
   <xsl:param name="source"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="
      $source
         => unparsed-text()
         => replace('&amp;nbsp;', '&amp;#x000A0;')
         => parse-xml()
   "/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: ... but as others have pointed out, the document is not well-formed, and you should if possible go to the source of the problem and fix it there.

Answer (score 1):

If the input document contains an `&nbsp;` entity reference that isn't declared in the DOCTYPE declaration, then it isn't a well-formed XML document, and therefore it isn't a well-formed XHTML document; and if it isn't well-formed, then Saxon can't handle it.

It would be best to look at the processing workflow that generated this ill-formed document and fix it so the documents it produces are well-formed.

If you can't do that, then you might be able to parse it as HTML. Saxon has an extension function `saxon:parse-html()`; or if your application is in Java then you could create a SAXSource that uses `validator.nu` as its XMLReader.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the tool [Tidy](https://www.html-tidy.org/) and convert html files into xhtml. It corrects all such things.

Just run tidy with the argument -asxml.